# Is this a reasonable way to maintain a log/audit table of changes to a mysql table?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers

I'm wanting to maintain log tables of changes to several tables in my schema.
I'm trying to set it up so that I don't need to list all the fields in my insert statement, so I have set up the log table to have the exact same structure as the master table - I'm just removing the auto-increment/primary key and making an adjustment to a timestamp.

Once I've established that this works, I'm planning to automate the set-up of the log tables and the triggers with a bit of dynamic sql.

Is this a reasonable approach?  Any problem with not having any primary key on the log table?

```
CREATE member (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_updated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

-- Add change log table
CREATE TABLE change_log.member_log LIKE member;
ALTER TABLE change_log.member_log CHANGE id id INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE change_log.member_log CHANGE last_updated last_updated DATETIME;
ALTER TABLE change_log.member_log DROP PRIMARY KEY;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER log_member_changes_on_update BEFORE UPDATE ON member FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO change_log.member_log SELECT * FROM member WHERE id = NEW.id; 
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Many thanks

Comment: I with there was a better way like creating only one trigger that executes on all the tables when they update or insert, verifying with `NEW` and `OLD` if there was alterations, but we can't. I usually do that via software creating an object that inserts on an audit table every time there is an insert or update in the database object I am using for interface with the user.

Comment: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/auditlog.html

This is the ultimate solution. You can read through how he has built it and you can do the same for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add an index on the `id` column if you expect to select by `id` often. Furthermore, it would probably be helpful if you could add information about who made the change. And maybe you want to consider logging inserts and deletes too? Other than that I think it is a perfectly reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider:

1. Create a table called "Audit";
2. Create a record in that table every time user creates a new record or update one;
3. This table should have:

   - the name of the table that was updated,
   - the number of the record,
   - the name or id of the user that made the change,
   - the action taken, like 'updated address' or 'new client created',
   - the `timestamp` of the moment that update was made

You have to insert data to this "Audit" table in the software, not from any trigger in the database or you will need to copy the trigger for each table.
Programming you could do one method to handle every table once.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a good idea. You probably want to add triggers for all events, ie insert, update and delete. With delete you'll have to insert the current timestamp into the audit table manually, as delete wont update the timestamp column.

Consider storing both old and new values in the audit table (ie double the number of non-id columns) because searching for when a value changed is difficult when only the current value is logged, but when you log both, it's easy:

```
where old_column1 != new_column1
```

It also makes finding the value at a particular time easy:

```
where someDateTime between old_last_updated and new_last_updated
```

I have successfully used exactly this approach.